# NDA for Take Home Challenge

Tags: non-disclosure

As a part of an interview process, I've been asked to solve a take home challenge. Before I can access the data, I've been asked to sign a NDA. The NDA is generic stuff which says everything belongs to the company, etc. etc. What is curious to me is that throughout the contract, I'm being referred to as a "contractor". Is that normal? I'm not being paid or compensated in any way to solve this challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not being paid or compensated in any way

Yes you are - you are being given the opportunity to be considered for a job. This is valid consideration (compensation) under contract law.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the time you have taken to answer this question.